# Is it possible to change the layout of the registration form using display suite?

Tags: users, display-suite

My registration form contains the following fields
-Name
-City
-Mobile
-Email
-Password
-Confirm Password
-Terms and Conditions (using legal module)

Is there some way to change the layout? I want it to appear something like this

```
************** ***************
*   TERMS    * *   Name      *
*     &      * *   City      *
*   COND.    * *   Mobile    *
* ************ *   Email     *
*   Submit   * *   Password  *
************** ***************
```

Comment: By using user-register.tpl you can have this.

Comment: is it possible to do this using display-suite

Comment: It's not possible with Display suite. You may go with custom `.tpl` file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, I don't think it is possible with display suite on its own but you may find this link helpful [Changing the layout of user profile edit page](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/90163/changing-the-layout-of-user-profile-edit-page). Display suite appears to only get you some of the way there.

Comment: Its not showing all the fields. Just the name, city and mobile

Comment: You may find this post useful http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/90163/changing-the-layout-of-user-profile-edit-page.